# Perform SQL Query WCF RIA Silverlight

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, silverlight-4.0, ria

I have created a database, linked it with DomainService's within my Silverlight Application. Now I want to be able to perform certain actions, such as Registration, Login etc. by using the service.

How would I be able to do this. I have preset methods created in the service, e.g. InsertUser but it only requires one parameter, so I'm not sure how it works. In the metadata I have all fields etc.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks.

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Users;
        }

public void InsertUser(User user)
        {
            if ((user.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Added);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Users.AddObject(user);
            }
        }
```

For retrieving User I have used (as a base from TBohnen.jnr code):

```
UserContext _userContext = new UserContext();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadOperation loGetUsers = _userContext.Load(_userContext.GetUsersQuery());
            loGetUsers.Completed += new EventHandler(loGetUsers_Completed);
        }

        void loGetUsers_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadOperation<Web.User> lo = (LoadOperation<Web.User>)sender;
            var user = _userContext.Users;
            MessageBox.Show(user.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please add an example method from your domain service, is it an IQuerable or an Invoke operation?

Comment: Added the code that was generated

Comment: Cool, gave an answer, let me know if you need something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to add a new user:

```
YourDomainContext dc = new YourDomainContext();
User userToAdd = new User();
//You will have to set your properties here as I don't know them, I will give an example.
userToAdd.username = "NewUser"; 
dc.User.Add(userToAdd);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

To retrieve your existing users:

```
YourDomainContext dc = new YourDomainContext();
LoadOperation loGetUsers = dc.Load(dc.GetUsersQuery());
loGetUsers.Completed += new EventHandler( loadOperation_Completed );// You will see there is a callback overloads as well

and then add this as well.

private void loadOperation_Completed( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    LoadOperation<User> lo = (LoadOperation<User>)sender;
    //Have a look at all the properties like lo.Error etc. but to see the retrieved users you can either use:
    var users = lo.AllEntities;
    //or if you declared your domaincontext as a class level parameter:
    var users = dc.User;
    foreach (Web.User user in users)
    {
        MessageBox.show(user.username);
    }
}
```

This will trigger an async call that get's all the users and will add it to the DomainContext and you will be able to access it through dc.User

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work, I can get dc.User.Add in but then from new User there's no such thing and I can't do the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks, works a treat now, the reason I wasn't get User was I had to use Web.User as I hadn't referenced it. Thanks now I can get somewhere in my application!

Comment: Can you let me know one thing, When retrieving users I had used, MessageBox.show(loGetUsers.toString()); and it just shows me something not related. I remember that you have to wait for the server to bring the data back to the application. How would that be put in the code to actually make it work by returning the correct values.

Comment: Ok, I've extended the load example, you can give an upvote if it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't working right for me, I have updated my question with the code that I have used, maybe you can see if there's anything wrong with it

Comment: It is a list of all the entities, not just one user, so to get the first user you can call: MessageBox.Show(user.First().username); where username is a string property in your Web.User Class, also update the sample to do a foreach loop of the users

Comment: Cool, there are a lot of different ways of doing things with ria, I suggest you have a look at a couple of videos, can mike your life alot easier!

Comment: I've been googling "WCF RIA Tutorials" yet to find information that isn't useful, I will have a deeper look though. Thanks again